# Simple way to display currency symbol in html2pdf for iText 7

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, html2pdf

I updated my code from `iText 5.0` to `iText 7` and `html2pdf 2.0` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/converting-html-to-pdf-using-itext) post. In earlier version rupee symbol was rendering properly, but because of `css` issue i changed the code. Now complete page is converting properly to pdf except rupee symbol.

1. Tried adding font in `html` style tag itself like `* { font-family: Arial; }`.
2. Changed value of rupee symbol from `&#x20b9`, `&#8377;` and also added directly ₹ , but no use.

My Html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { font-family: Arial; }
</style>
<title>HTML div</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0in; padding-left: 60px;">
    <div style="font-size: 450%; text-indent: 150px;">
        <strong>BUY <span style="color: #ff420e;">2</span> GET
        </strong>
    </div>
    </p>
    <div
        style="float: left; display: inline-block; margin: 10px; text-align: right; font-size: 70%; line-height: 27; transform: rotate(270deg);">Offer
        Expiry Date : 30/11/2017</Div>
    <div
        style="float: left; display: inline-block; margin: 10px; text-align: right; font-size: 350%;">
        ₹
        <!-- &#x20b9; -->
    </div>
    <div
        style="float: left; display: inline-block; margin: auto; font-size: 1500%; color: red; font-weight: bold;">99</div>
    <div
        style="float: left; display: inline-block; margin: 10px; text-align: left; font-size: 250%; line-height: 10;">OFF</div>
    <div
        style="position: absolute; height: 40px; font-size: 250%; line-height: 600px; color: red; text-indent: 50px">Pepsi
        2.25 Pet Bottle ltr</div>
    <div
        style="position: absolute; height: 40px; font-size: 245%; line-height: 694px; text-indent: 50px">
        MRP: &#x20b9; <span style="color: #ff420e;">654</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Code :

```
public class Test {

    final static String DEST = "D://Workspace_1574973//POP//sample_12.pdf";
    final static String SRC = "D://Workspace_1574973//POP//src//com//resources//test.html";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        createPdf(SRC, DEST);

    }

    public static void createPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException {

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest));
    }

}
```

Earlier code, which was working with symbols.

```
            log.info("Creating file start");
            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("font_check.pdf"));
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
            document.open();

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileTemplate.getBytes());
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
            document.close();
            file.close();

            log.info("Creating file end");
```

Is there any simple approach to achieve this, with minimal and optimized code ? 
Because I've to generate thousands of pdf in one go, So the performance should not affect.
Please let me know, if anyone achieved this through latest version.

Edit : Also how to set particular paper type in this like `A6`, `A3`, `A4` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are not mad, because I don't have reputation to write simple comments... so I'll post a full answer instead.  I parse HTML for my work, and I read SO sometimes.  There is a lot on the subject regarding UTF-8 here.  Most software systems support the "greater than char #256" (UTF-8) codes - for instance the Indian Rupee Symbol.  However, most of the time the programmer has to include a specific request for such a desired behavior, explicitly.

In HTML, for instance - adding this line usually helps:

```
String UTF8MetaTag = "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />";
```

Anyway, not having used HTMLToPDF - I might not be the right guy to post answers to your questions - but, because I have dealt with UTF-8 foreign language characters for three years, I know that setting a software setting to handle the 65,000 or so chars is usually VERY EASY, BUT ALSO ***ALWAYS*** VERY MANDATORY.

Here is an SO post about using HTMLToPDF and UTF-8 to handle Japanese Kanji characters.  Most likely, it should handle all UTF-8, but that is not a guarantee.

[HTML2PDF support for japanese language(utf8) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673676/html2pdf-support-for-japanese-languageutf8-is-not-working)

Here are a few posts about it using HTML2PDF in PHP:

[Converting html 2 pdf (php) using hebrew returns "???"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183530/converting-html-2-pdf-php-using-hebrew-returns)

[Having æøå chars in HTML2PDF charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301310/having-%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5-chars-in-html2pdf-charset)

Comment: the question is about itext7 , the char related thing i already achieved in itext5, but the same charset is not working with higher version

Comment: ? ? - Here's the title written on your post: "Simple way to display rupess symbol in html2pdf" ...  Anyway, I was bringing up how "higher order" UTF-8 chars have worked in the software environments that I have programmed...  Mentioning it because I program Mandarin Chinese (and all the symbols required)...  It has always been (for me) finding how to set for allowing UTF-8...  I also program Spanish too - and it's the same.

Comment: UTF-8 encoding worked perfectly for iText version 5, the same encoding and same html page design is not working with higher version of iText (version 7). Anyway, i found workaround by using currency image symbol :-(